# Error on Compiling Command-T Plugin (clang)

Tags: neovim

While running the `make` command following [this documentation](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/c797e8b76155e24ebdf180cef28e1a409604492e/doc/command-t.txt#L315) I got this error message:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.6.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib'
```

So I go to check my Xcode files:

```
command-t ❯ cd /../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX
MacOSX.sdk/ MacOSX11.1.sdk@
```

Here is what I got.

I think I'm missing **MacOSX11.6.Internal.sdk** so I can accomplish this task.

Is my assumption right?

If so, how can I get that specific SDK?

If not, what's your advice?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to ask the plugin developer (_e.g._, file an issue on GitHub). They have the most experience with this. And, other than the compilation being necessary to use a vim plugin, the question as posed has nothing to do with vim. (In case no has said it yet: Welcome to [vi.se]!)

Comment: I just felt that way I should ask this question to plugin developer. Thank you for your comment and your welcome, it's so heartwarming.